# Swift more complex array dictionary

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

I'm trying to count the number of times (in one hour interval) the time which a person drinks a glass of water during a day, I can't figure how to build this data structure properly, the expected data will look something like this:

```
day1 = [hour interval: [time, time, time], hour interval: [time], hour interval: [time], hour:[time]]
```

It prints an empty array...so far I have this:

```
var counts = [String:Array<NSDate>]()
var dict = [[NSDate:Array<[String:Array<NSDate>]>]]()

//datesArray -> is an array of dates from something like monday to friday
/*
datesArray:

2016-07-23
2016-07-24
2016-07-25
2016-07-26
2016-07-27
2016-07-28
2016-07-29
2016-07-30
*/


    for date in datesArray {

           //tempDoses has the times when the user took the glass of water 
/*
tempDoses:

2016-07-28 23:50:50 +0000
2016-07-26 13:06:57 +0000
2016-07-25 08:47:52 +0000
2016-07-25 08:46:47 +0000
2016-07-25 08:46:06 +0000
2016-07-24 23:25:07 +0000
2016-07-24 14:18:11 +0000
2016-07-24 13:58:35 +0000
2016-07-22 09:10:59 +0000
2016-07-22 09:10:26 +0000
2016-07-22 09:09:28 +0000
*/


              for temp in tempDoses {

                    if calendar.isDate(date, inSameDayAsDate: temp.logTime)



                        let dateformatter = NSDateFormatter()

                        dateformatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"

                        let myDate = dateformatter.stringFromDate(temp.logTime)



                        let h = self.getHour(myDate)

                        for m in counts {
                         var o = m

                            if o.0 == h {
                                o.1.append(temp.logTime)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                if counts.count > 0 {
                    dict.append([date:[counts]])
                    counts.removeAll()
                }else{
                    dict.append([date:[]])
                }
            }
```

Expected result:

```
    2016-07-21 = []
    2016-07-22 = ["10": [09:10, 09:13]]
    2016-07-23 = []
    2016-07-24 = ["15": [14:18], "14": [13:12, 13:56]]
    2016-07-25 = ["09": [08:33, 08:40], "00": [23:10]]
    2016-07-26 = ["14": [13:33]]
    2016-07-27 = []
    2016-07-28 = []
```

Comment: To just save the trouble of figuring out what your source looks like, can you edit your question to include the expected input and output?

Comment: Ok, sorry for the confusion

Comment: I made some comments also

Comment: I still don't see what your input is. What's the value of your `datesArray`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expected output doesn't match up to your input! For example, on `2016-07-22`:

```
// Input
2016-07-22 09:10:59 +0000
2016-07-22 09:10:26 +0000
2016-07-22 09:09:28 +0000

// My expected output
2016-07-22 = [9: ["09:10", "09:09"]]

// Your expected output:
2016-07-22 = ["10": [09:10, 09:13]]
```

Play around with the code below until you get what you want. **Pay special attention to the time zone** as it's the major source of bugs when dealing with `NSDate`:

```
let timeZone = NSTimeZone(forSecondsFromGMT: 0)

let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
calendar.timeZone = timeZone

let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
formatter.timeZone = timeZone

var dict = [NSDate : [Int: [String]]]()

for date in datesArray {
    let dailyDoses = doses
                        .filter { calendar.startOfDayForDate($0.logTime) == date }
                        .sort { $0.logTime.timeIntervalSince1970 < $1.logTime.timeIntervalSince1970 }

    dict[date] = [Int: [String]]()

    dailyDoses.forEach {
        let hour = calendar.component(.Hour, fromDate: $0.logTime)
        let str = formatter.stringFromDate($0.logTime)

        if dict[date]![hour] == nil {
            dict[date]![hour] = [String]()
        }
        if !(dict[date]![hour]!.contains { $0 == str }) {
            dict[date]![hour]!.append(str)
        }
    }
}

// Print the result
for date in datesArray {
    print(date, "=", dict[date]!)
}

/* Output:
2016-07-22 00:00:00 +0000 = [9: ["09:09", "09:10"]]
2016-07-23 00:00:00 +0000 = [:]
2016-07-24 00:00:00 +0000 = [14: ["14:18"], 23: ["23:25"], 13: ["13:58"]]
2016-07-25 00:00:00 +0000 = [8: ["08:46", "08:47"]]
2016-07-26 00:00:00 +0000 = [13: ["13:06"]]
2016-07-27 00:00:00 +0000 = [:]
2016-07-28 00:00:00 +0000 = [23: ["23:50"]]
*/
```

Comment: Great answer and thanks for the warning on the dates format :)